# How to strip noisy pattern at the end of string?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a list of strings (len 10000), some of them looks like

```
Belin (*) 9
München 12
```

I want to strip away number and (*) at the end of string to get pure city name

```
Berlin
München
```

can I use rstrip on this ?

Comment: Are any of your cities more than 1 word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regular expression function [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to remove (*) (`\(\*\)`) and digits (`\d+`) with extra leading spaces (`\s*`):

```
>>> cities = [
...     'Belin (*) 9',
...     'München 12',
...     'Los Angeles 9'
... ]
>>> [re.sub('\s*\(\*\)|\s*\d+', '', city) for city in cities]
['Belin', 'München', 'Los Angeles']
```

Using [`str.rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip), you need to specify all characters to remove:

```
>>> [city.rstrip(' 0123456789(*)') for city in cities]
['Belin', 'München', 'Los Angeles']
```